select2 x-eitable problem with not showing opt group
I have the below code which has two problems;

it does not show the option Group which i am trying to setup as i am getting Array of Objects from database

once i edit and select select team, it does not let me trigger the select 2nd time.


Here is the code i tried
$('#boats c').editable({
        type: "select",
        dataType: "json",
        placement: "top",
        showbuttons: false,

        display: function(value, sourceData, response, pk) {
            var key = $(this).attr("data-pk");
            var $that = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $that.editable('option', 'source', 'results.cfm?process=getTeams&key=' + key + '&i=' + Math.random());
            }, 0);
            $(this).html(response); // display the correct value instead of 'empty'

            // Initialize Select2
            $that.editable().on('shown', function(e, editable) {
                editable.input.$input.select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Team",
                    allowClear: true,
                    width: '100%'
                });

                // Set the default value to the first option from the JSON array
                editable.input.$input.on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
                    var firstOption = $(this).find('option:first').val();
                    $(this).val(firstOption).trigger('change');
                });
            });
        },
        success: function(response, newValue) {
            if (response == 'errorEvent') {
                swal({
                    text: 'This team is no longer registered in any events.',
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: false,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#EF5350",
                    confirmButtonText: "OK",
                    closeOnConfirm: true
                });
            } else if (response.substr(0, 4) == 'This') {
                return response;
            } else {
                // Assuming response is an array of objects with 'div' and 'team' properties
                var teamsByDiv = {};
                response.forEach(function(item) {
                    if (item.div && item.div.trim() !== '') {
                        if (!teamsByDiv[item.div]) {
                            teamsByDiv[item.div] = [];
                        }
                        teamsByDiv[item.div].push(item.team);
                    }
                });

                // Prepend the "Select Team" option
                var select2Input = $('#boats c').editable().data('editable').input.$input;
                select2Input.empty(); // Clear existing options
                select2Input.append($('<option>').val('-1').text('Select Team'));

                // Create optgroup elements
                Object.keys(teamsByDiv).forEach(function(div) {
                    var optgroup = $('<optgroup>').attr('label', div);
                    teamsByDiv[div].forEach(function(team) {
                        optgroup.append($('<option>').val(team).text(team));
                    });
                    select2Input.append(optgroup);
                });

                // Update Select2 with new options
                select2Input.select2('destroy').select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Team",
                    allowClear: true,
                    width: '100%'
                });
            }
        }
    });

here is the JSON repsonse
[
  {
    "divid": "",
    "text": " Select Team...",
    "temp": "",
    "div": "-1",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "divid": 1298,
    "text": "Ducks",
    "temp": "DUCKS",
    "div": "Division #3",
    "value": 6270
  },
  {
    "divid": 1164,
    "text": "Lightning",
    "temp": "LIGHTNING",
    "div": "Division #1",
    "value": 6059
  },
  {
    "divid": 1164,
    "text": "Rangers",
    "temp": "RANGERS",
    "div": "Division #1",
    "value": 6261
  }
]

the above code should should show two optiongroups because it has two different divisions, if it will have on, it will show one and if all div is empty except the first one, whih is -1, it means there is no optiongroup
